# Workspace indicator that works with more than 4 workspaces?

Tags: unity, 14.04, indicator, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I'm using ubuntu with more than the default 4 workspaces. The workspace indicator icon in the left sidebar only shows 4 workspaces. So i can't see in which workspace I'm currently are.

Is there a plugin or something that can show i.e. all 8 configured workspaces with the current workspace highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [workspace indicator for ubuntu](https://github.com/maho2nd/enhanced-ubuntu-workspace-indicator) on github. It should work for all kind of workspace compositions.

[image: ubuntu works]

Comment: I looked at that indicator and it appears to use Java.  IMHO invoking a JVM just for an indicator is a little top heavy!

Comment: Yes, you need a JVM. I also think something like a python script is more suitable for an indicator. But this is all i found.

Comment: I took a quick look at the code.  It's quite simple to determine how many workspaces are active and also to switch between them - all uses wmctrl.  The hard part is making the indicator interface display it nicely/simply.  I went overboard and set up 4 x 4 and the indicator "icon" is just too small...so some other way would be needed for the presentation part beyond say two rows.  Left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Would an indicator suffice, rather than an icon in the launcher (left sidebar)?  Try `indicator-workspaces` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/38058/67335).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of workspaces in the default workspace indicator, using simple cli commands:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 3

gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 3
```

Comment: It doesn't work on 14.04. However, it refers to workspace numbers not the indicator.