# How to change workspace switcher icon when using more workspaces?

Tags: unity, icons, indicator, workspaces

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I would like to see current workspace position while using  more than 4 workspaces. When I changed number of WS with compiz-config/unity-tweak/ubuntu tweak I realized that my workspace switcher icon remained unchanged. Although I am now using 9 workspaces, icon is still showing 4 and doing nothing when moving between themselves. It's not very practical to always remember current position.

So I was trying another icon, called workspace indicator - http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/05/10-useful-application-indicators-for.html but I got an ImportError: No module named appindicator.

I also found adding workspaces manual with immediately changing icon: http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/use-more-than-four-workspaces-in-ubuntu-12-04/
but it's not working for me (number of ws changed, icon stayed the same).

Could you help me to recognize workspace when using more than four of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/77160/how-can-i-tell-what-workspace-i-am-in-with-unity?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/500993/workspace-indicator-that-works-with-more-than-4-workspaces?rq=1